# Перевод пиксельных координат в географические на сервере

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Цель: накрыть гексогональной сеткой территорию страны. 
Как и можно ли вообще при помощи Yandex maps API перевести пиксельные координаты в географические на стороне сервера (NODEJS)? Ничего отрисовывать на сервере не нужно.
Из входных данных имею:
1. центры и вершины гексагонов (в пикселях)
2. ширину и высоту пользовательского экрана (в пикселях)
3. границы пользовательской карты, bbox,(в географических координатах).

Comment: а какую задачу вы хотите в итоге решить?

Comment: Мне нужно покрыть территорию страны гексогональной сеткой. Это около трех млн объектов. Сейчас, с помощью библиотеки D3 не клиенте я формирую центры гексагонов в пиксельных координатах, затем формирую вершины гексагонов в пиксельных координатах, потом все точки преобразую в географические координаты и отправляю их на сервер для записи в БД.

Comment: С небольшим количеством объектов (200тыс) такой подход приемлем. Дальше страница отваливается по таймауту.

Comment: Идеально было бы передать центры гексагонов в пиксельных координатах на сервер и все остальные расчеты производить там.

Comment: Не стоит делать гексагоны отдельными объектами, попробуйте генерировать на сервере слой и накладывать его на карту. Так не будет тормозить.

Comment: генерировать на сервере слой? Как это?

Comment: Дело в том, что гексагоны нужны именно в географических координатах.

Comment: @ColdPol см. Технология активных областей > [Картиночный слой](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/hotspots/image-layer.html). Другого способа отобразить такое количество объектов через API не существует.